# Internet monitoring on a network

Tags: router, internet, bandwidth

I have a network from 20 PCs and around 15 cell phones. Sometimes the internet is slow while there is no problem on the ISP side. So I assume someone is downloading a torrent or streaming.

How can I know the bandwidth usage for every PC and is there a way to configure a quota for each user? As an example every user have only 15 GB / Month.

Comment: This smells of a (small) corporate IT network, which is off topic here. There are definitely ways to this but you will need some enterprise grade equipment... Router/firewall with monitoring capabilities comes to mind. There maybe other network sniffing devices that can do the measurements, but implementing restrictions requires something quite a bit beyond the typical SOHO router.

Comment: If you are at all familar with Linux I would suggest checking out ntop, which is a free utility that does exactly what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is depending on your infrastructure, but I will assume a simple setup where you switch the traffic internally and have one connection to the outside.

To monitor the traffic you could use a scanner like wireshark and setup promiscuous mode on the switch to capture the traffic.

To put quota on the connections of the users you could use a Pfsense box or something similar. It has the capability but I think there will be some scripting involved still. (I have no test box at hand and it has been a while since i used it)

The idea is that you sens all traffic to the outside (wan) trough this box so you can put limits in place as you see fit.